# Two Bootstrap-image-carousel are not working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am doing a project in laravel, in which i have to make two carousels.
Everything was working when i made one.
But when made another one,
On clicking the navigation buttons on the second, first one moves, and slso second isnt showing any pictures.
I want these two carousels to work separately.

This is my html

```
<!-- Latest Slide Show Start -->

<div class="container imageSlideContainer my-3">
  <div class="headingSlider">Latest Products</div>
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
      <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slideImage w-100" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
            @foreach ($productsLatest as $product)  
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  col-xl-3">
                    <img class="card-img-top imageSlide" src="/storage/{{$product->image}}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-price">{{$product->price}}</h5>
                      <h6 class="card-title text-center">{{$product->name}}</h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="imageIcon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="imageIcon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
          
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Latest Slide Show End -->

<!-- Best Slide Show Start -->

<div class="container imageSlideContainer my-3">
  <div class="headingSlider">Best Selling</div>
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
      <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slideImage w-100" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
            @foreach ($productsBest as $product)  
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  col-xl-3">
                    <img class="card-img-top imageSlide" src="/storage/{{$product->image}}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-price">{{$product->price}}</h5>
                      <h6 class="card-title text-center">{{$product->name}}</h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="imageIcon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="imageIcon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
          
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Best Slide Show End -->
```

This is my JS

```
// Images Slide Show Start //
  $('.carousel-item').eq(0).addClass('active'); 

$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 500000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var minPerSlide = 4;
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    
    for (var i=0;i<minPerSlide;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
});

$( ".imageSlideContainer" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('shadow-lg').css('cursor', 'pointer'); 
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('shadow-lg');
  }
);

// Images Slide Show End //
```

This is css

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
      display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
      display: block;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

/* display 3 */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(33.333%);
  }
  
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-33.333%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Both of the carousels have the same id `recipeCarousel`

Comment: hello Sir, i am getting data, now. i wasnt getting any data for second carousel, now the problem is when i click on the second carousel's navigation, first one moves.

Comment: so i have to add different ids to both of them, and then call separately?

Comment: Sir i added different classes to both.`$('.carousel1').carousel({
  interval: 500000
})

$('.carousel2').carousel({
  interval: 500000
})`

Comment: and changed html to `<div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel carousel1 slideImage w-100" data-ride="carousel1">` and `<div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel carousel2 slideImage w-100" data-ride="carousel2">`

Comment: Sounds good. I believe that you also need to change the href of the navigation links. e.g. `<a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href=".carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">` and `<a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href=".carousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">`

Comment: ohh it worked, i am so stupid. i changed the ids and then refer the same to buttons. Thank You

Comment: You are not :) It's happening to all of us every day..